# Why Webpack lazy loading loads all files from a folder?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, lazy-loading

I'm trying to import `i18n` files dynamically using `webpack`:

```
function getI18n(lang) {
  return import(/* webpackChunkName "i18n/[request]" */ `./locales/${lang}.json`)
  .then(/*whatever*/)
}
```

But even before that function been called I can see in a developer tool that all the files from that folder were loaded:

- i18n/en.json.js
- i18n/ru.json.js
- i18n/nl.json.js
- i18n/nw.json.js

And etc.

That's not what I want. **I want to lazy load required chunk dynamically in runtime**.

Fun thing, if I'll rename files `ru` -> `ru2` and `nw` -> `nw2` and change import to use path with number 2, like this: `./locales/${lang}2.json` it will load only the files `i18n/ru2.json.js` and `i18n/nw2.json.js` and will ignore those who has no `2` character in the name. So I guess it's operates with some kind of regexp instead of exact match.

Thank you

**P.S.** Honestly I use `vuejs` and `typescript`, so the problem might be somewhere in between. I've been trying to follow this example [vuei18n lazy load](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/lazy-loading.html) with mine code.

Comment: when are you calling `getI18n()`

Comment: I don't call it so far, it should be called on a button click. Even if that function is never used but been exported - that import stuff happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was easy:

**`vue-cli` has enable 'prefetch' settings by default.** (which breaks the whole idea of lazy-loading)

- You can turn off `prefetch` in your webpack settings.
- In case you are using "vue-cli",you have to extend your `vue.config.js`:

  `chainWebpack: config => config.plugin.delete('prefetch')`

Hope this will helps

Answer (score 1):

Webpack doesn't know which file in that directory you'll need at runtime so it needs to include all files in the bundle. (https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression)

Comment: Okay, that's make sense. But it's not clear for me - how to avoid that? Or maybe  the whole question should be changed: how to lazy load chunks in runtime properly?

Comment: Instead of doing an import with a dynamic value, you could restructure your `getI18n` function to something like:

```
const langs = {
  en: () => import('./locales/en.json'),
  ru: () => import('./locales/ru.json')
}

function getI18n(lang) {
  return langs[lang].then(...)
}
```

Then webpack will know ahead of time which files to include in the bundle, but they will be in separate chunks, so only the langs that are used would be sent to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

To disable vue cli prefech here is the config I used for local languages. Can also find this in vue cli documentation https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#prefetch.

vue.config.js

```js
   ...
   chainWebpack: config => {
    // remove the prefetch plugin
    // config.plugins.delete("prefetch");

    // or:
    // modify its options:
    config.plugin("prefetch").tap(options => {
      options[0].fileBlacklist = options[0].fileBlacklist || [];
      options[0].fileBlacklist.push(/lang(.)+?\.js$/);
      options[0].fileBlacklist.push(/lang(.)+?\.js.map$/);
      return options;
    });
  },
  ...
```